# How to get first child of props.children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm very new to React.js and Typescript

Now, I'm trying to retrieve first element of `props.children`.

I understand that parent component get `props.children` as `React.element` or `React.element[]`.

What I want to do is assign first children to a variable.

```
interface TempProps {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    url: string
    setEnable?: any,
    isEnable?: boolean
    remove?: Function,
}
```

```
export default ( props: TempProps) => {

    validate(props);

    const children = props.children;

    // I want to check if props.children is React.ReactElement or React.ReactElement[]
```

So, If I try to retrieve the first child using `props.children[0]`, the compiler shows me an error.

Is there anyone who can give me a tip?

Comment: `I want to check if props.children is React.ReactElement or React.ReactElement[]` ---> please try: `if (children && Array.isArray(children)` to check if `children` is an array or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`React.Children.toArray(props.children)[0]`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray) to get the first child.

| `props.children` | `React.Children.toArray(props.children)[0]` |
| --- | --- |
| `null` | `undefined` |
| `undefined` | `undefined` |
| Just one child | that one child |
| More than one child | the first child |

```js
const MyComponent = ({ label, children }) => {
  const firstChild = React.Children.toArray(children)[0];
  return (
    <div>
      For {label} - Got: {firstChild === undefined ? 'undefined' : firstChild}
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
  <div>
    <MyComponent label="null">{null}</MyComponent>
    <MyComponent label="undefined"></MyComponent>
    <MyComponent label="one child"><span>one</span></MyComponent>
    <MyComponent label="two children"><span>first</span><span>second</span></MyComponent>
  </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```